# Unknown custom element: x when using Buefy

Tags: vue.js, buefy

I follows the Buefy guideline by

```
npm install Buefy
```

In main.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue';

import Buefy from 'buefy';

import axios from 'axios';
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';

import 'buefy/dist/buefy.css';

import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.use(VueAxios, axios, Buefy);

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

In the Home.vue (view)

```
<section>
    <b-button @click="clickMe">
       Click Me
    </b-button>
</section>
```

Then when I run, I get this error

```
Unknown custom element: <b-button> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <Home> at src/views/Home.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
```

I think Vue.use(Buefy) loads all components?

What am I missing to make Buefy works?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove axios from the Vue instance Vue.use() because axios is not a plugin yet. You can instead use an operator with it instead to access it globally.

```
import Axios from 'axios'
Vue.prototype.$http = Axios;
```

Now you will be able to access using this.$http.post("https://api.com").then().catch()
Please note that use takes the first argument, You should use multiple Vue.use() to allow plugins to work well

Answer (score 0):

I had to include the following lines in my `tests/setup.js` so that components are registered during test setup.

```js
import Buefy from 'buefy';
Vue.use(Buefy)
```

My `main.js` was not executed for tests.

I am new to testing with jest, so maybe this is a monstrosity, and there are better ways to do it. But it worked for me.